# How do you validate file paths in TCL?

Tags: string, validation, tcl

Given a string, I'd like to know if the string represents a valid file path. I've looked at `[file isfile <string>]` and `[file isdirectory <string>]` but it seems those two return `false` if the given string isn't pointing to an existing file/directory. I'm merely interested in the validity of the string.

Comment: What do you actually understand by “valid file path” in the first path? What do you want to achieve with this information?

Comment: @DonalFellows That's a good point... I didn't think this question through very well. Is there a way for me to scrap this post?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much every string is a valid file path. Can you give some examples of what you consider invalid file paths?

You can use `file pathtype` to check if the path is absolute. Also `file split` and `file normalize` may be useful, depending on what you really need.

Comment: Seems like the problem here is to precisely define what "validity of the string" means. Seems hard to do when so many strings are valid file names. Wonder what the real problems is.

Comment: Almost every string is valid on true POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's a particular way to do that.
I suppose you could try:

```
set fn /home/bll/mytest.txt
set fail true
if { [file exists $fn] } {
  set fail false
} else {
  try {
    set fh [open $fn w]
    set fail false
    file delete $fn
  } on error {err res} {
  }
}
```

Even if the above works, certain characters may cause issues if you use
the filename in an external command line.

I strip the following characters simply to avoid possible command line problems:

```
 * : " ? < > | [:cntrl:]
```

I have this list as possibly problematical for unix:

```
 * & [] ? ' " < > |
```

And this list for windows:

```
 * : () & ^ |  < > ' "
```

Also, a trailing dot is illegal for windows directory names.

And slashes or backslashes can cause issues as those are directory separators.

Comment: Some filenames are perfectly legal, but I wouldn't  want to try and work with them.